# Access Master object fields from child object in managed package

Tags: soql

I have a child object - affiliation (in a managed package). It's got M/D relationships to both the Contact and Account standard object in salesforce.

How do I access the contact object's firstname and lastname from within the affiliation object.

For example,

```
Select pac__contact__c, contact.firstname, contact.lastname
from pac__affiliation__c
```

This query isn't working and throwing an error at the contact.firstname field. If I remove the contact. fields, it's working fine.

Note pac - is the namespace prefix for the object in the managed pkg.

Comment: It should be contact__r.firstname as contact is a custom field right

Comment: Eric, Contact is the standard sf object. btw, I tried contact__r. firstname and it didn't work.

Comment: But Contact on your custom object is not a standard field, you cannot use Contact. it is either Contact__c or Contact__r depending on use

Comment: Eric, you are correct. It's contact__r with the pac prefix that did it. Thanks for your inputs. I'll mark the answer down as correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The prefix of your package is "pac" so you have to add this prefix to the fields to be able to request them. You can read the Salesforce documentation about it [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_namespace_prefix.htm).

Also, you can query the look up relationships fields by adding the suffix "__r" to your custom field. As you can see [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_lookup.htm).

So, this should work:

```
Select pac__contact__c, pac__contact__r.firstname, pac__contact__r.lastname from pac__affiliation__c
```

Comment: Martin, this solution worked. Thx for your help.